# Is it possible to create two foreign keys on table and conditionally enforce them with SqlAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `TableA`. I want rows in this table to have a relationship to either two other tables, `TableB` or `TableC`. A row in `Table A` should never have both relationships simultaneously, only one or the other. The reason why is because the the code gets passed a plain uuid. That uuid is either the parent's uuid or the child's (so either a uuid in `TableB` or a uuid in `TableC`. After the code determines which table the uuid belongs to, it should enforce that foreign key constraint, but not the other, when creating a new row in `TableA`. Is this possible to do with SqlAlchemy?

Below is some pseudocode on how I am defining the foreign key relationships in `TableA`.

```
parent_id: str = Column(String, ForeignKey('TableB.uuid'), nullable=False, index=True)
child_id: str = Column(String, ForeignKey('TableC.uuid'), nullable=False, index=True)
```

Comment: This is perfectly possible in SQL. You'll need to add an extra "XOR" constraint to check one and only one of them is null at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce that the foreign key relationship only exists for some rows in a table in PostgreSQL - foreign key relationships are defined for the whole table. However, if you want any specific row to *not* be linked to some other row in the table linked in your foreign key, then just store a NULL value for that column in that row. Or in other words, if you want to insert a row into `TableA(a_id, b_fk, c_fk)`, but you don't want this row to reference `TableB` or `TableC`, then just insert NULL values for `b_fk` and `c_fk`. Simply make the `b_fk` and `c_fk` columns NULLable in `TableA` - you don't need to do anything to `TableB` or `TableC` to make this logic work.

But the above approach doesn't completely solve your problem. If you also want to enforce that every row in `TableA` MUST reference at least `TableB` OR `TableC` but NOT both, then you can define a row-level constraint in `TableA` to check that `(a_fk IS NULL AND b_fk IS NOT NULL) OR (a_fk IS NOT NULL AND b_fk IS NULL)`. Note that this logic isn't the most efficient or concise, but I wrote it this way because it's the most explicit about what it's checking. If you want a more performance-efficient approach (which matters more if you have a lot of rows, or if you're going to have a lot more of these only-one-of-several-columns-has-a-value types of situations in your DB) then I recommend you check out [this answer to another question by Alex Martelli.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960591/5619073)